# np.ravel_multi_index: ValueError: invalid entry in coordinates array

Tags: python, numpy, multi-index, valueerror

I want to use np.ravel_multi_index to Converts a tuple of index arrays into an array of flat indices (like sub2ind in MATLAB). But I have an error:
ValueError: invalid entry in coordinates array

Here is my code:

BCross and Pixel are (128,128,2) numpy array.

```
c = 1
for i in range (0, 128):
    for j in range (0, 128):
        if Gap[i,j]==0:
IndI[c] = np.ravel_multi_index((BCross[i,j,0].astype(int), Pixel[i,j,0].astype(int),BCross[i,j,1].astype(int), Pixel[i,j,1].astype(int)), (10, 24, 10, 24), order = 'F')
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me to solve this error.

Comment: Seems like there either must be values in `BCross` greater than 10 or in `Pixel` that are greater than 24.

Comment: `np.ravel_multi_index((1,2,3,40),(10, 24, 10, 24))` produces the same error message.  See the too-large 40?

Comment: Thanks for help. That is right. The  values in BCross greater than 10 or in Pixel that were greater than 24. I corrected it.